# Where can I propose an increase in the number of allowable tags on a Stack Overflow question?

Tags: support, tags, site-recommendation, limits, tag-limit

I would like to propose an increase of number of tags allowed per question from 5 to 8. Where is the best place to post my proposal?

Comment: @Robert [tag:stackoverflow] is missing :)

Comment: @Rubén the answer would be the same if it was about SU or any other site - post on the per-site meta.

Comment: @RobertColumbia In such case then the title might the edited to make it a canonical question, right?

Comment: @Rubén yes that makes sense, but there is already an answer that is specific to SO.

Comment: In that case we "need" more tags here too :D

Comment: Tony, a few example links to questions that would benefit greatly from your suggestion might encourage a better reception of your question.

Answer (score 6):

[Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (Meta.SO) would be the correct place but in all honesty increasing the number of tags would be a very bad idea.

What is your reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: 0


I agree, but there are situations where involvement of many technologies /paradigms are norm of the day. In my specific case problem/solution involves Containerized applications(namely Sql Server, Webthings.IO Gateway , MQTT , Grafana) and I am seeking advise/opinion on how I can improve optimize IOT, ESP32 using other related technologies like Websockets,SSE (Server sent events) etc.

Comment: @TonyP frankly it sounds like your desire to add more tags reflects that your question is too broad.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, If I could narrow the question to the limit of tags, I would not be expressing what is required

Comment: Tags are not intended to be included for each tool/technology/abstract concept that is mentioned in the question

Comment: Problem/Solution involves many technologies(TAGS ?) and want to solicit advice/opinion from those (Tagged) experts.

Comment: @TonyP - asking for opinion is definitely a bad idea. We pretty much explicitly avoid opinion based questions.